# Wsgen usage with javaSE

Tags: jax-ws, wsgen

I'm studying how to build and publish Jax-WS web services using only javaSE 6 or later. The book I'm reading says that, for document-style ws, you need to call the wsgen utility before publishing the ws in order to create the java classes that act as wrappers for the data in the request and response messages. However, I tried to publish the ws without calling wsgen and everything seems to work fine: Endpoint.publish publishes the ws instance and the request and response messages are wrapped as expected (I'm using SoapUI to test the WS).

The version of my jdk is 1.7 and the jax-ws version is 2.2.4. The book speaks about jax-ws 2.1. Is it possible that jax-ws 2.2 automatically calls wsgen or generates the wrappers on the fly?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Nico

Answer (score 1):

I found this note on the book when speaking about how to generate the wsdl using wsgen:

"In the current Metro release, the Endpoint publisher automatically generates the
wsgen artifacts if the programmer does not..... In time this convenient feature of the Metro release will make its way into core Java so that the wsgen step in document-style services can be avoided."

I think this is what happens with current versions of Jax-WS.